# What specific features make Scala a 'more functional' language than Groovy?

Tags: scala, groovy, functional-programming

People say that Groovy is imperative, and Scala is more like a functional language.

But Groovy supports high order functions, and immutable variables so in theory, you can write functional code in it.

What specific features make it easier to write functional code in Scala than in Groovy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write functional code in C! If being a functional language is simply a yes/no question, and the only requirement is "in theory you can write functional code in it", then pretty much every language I can think of is "functional".

To be clear, I'm going to say that when I talk about functional programming I'm primarily thinking about *pure* functional programming. I know some would object to this and say that use of features like higher order functions, closures, etc that have come from the functional world is the more important criteria, and that using these features and also using side effects is still functional programming. I consider things higher order functions and closures to be extremely valuable additions to imperative programming, but I don't consider adding them to your toolkit to move you over the line into a different *kind* of programming, so if we're going to have a grand distinction between "functional" and "not functional" then I think it's more useful for it to be a distinction between pure functional and imperative programming.

What it really comes down to in my experience is the "attitude" of the language and its ecosystem, rather than a specific set of technical features. It's about what's considered "normal" in a language, because that's what ends up informing the API design of the standard libraries and all the other third party code you'll be dealing with.

Scala is clearly designed with functional programming very much in mind. Even without reading statements to that effect by its designers, we can see it in language features like class fields being immutable unless you specifically ask for them to be mutable, case classes and pattern matching to make immutable plain old data structures easy to use, and for-comprehensions specifically aimed at letting you write looping code without using mutation (traditional for/while loops by definition **cannot** do anything useful without at least local side effects).

But what's almost more important is the standard library; because they expect you to be writing pure functional code, the libraries are explicitly designed to support this: all the important basic immutable collection types are there (there are mutable versions, but the immutable ones are the default), and just generally most of the functionality a standard library needs was implemented with the idea that programmers would want to access this functionality through an interface that fits well into functional code. The whole package is designed with functional programming highly in mind (though of course it's also designed not to get in the way when you *don't* want to do functional programming).

Groovy I've only just started learning at work, but my initial impressions are that its level of "functionalness" is similar to that of Python (which I've used extensively). It has higher order functions and lambdas, but much of the APIs you interact with were designed primarily for imperative use. It looks a little better than Python in that it *has* immutable collections<sup>1</sup>, but mutability is still the default, and so nobody thinks twice about making an interface that requires the uses of side effects.

If you are attempting to program functionally in a language (and library ecosystem) that isn't designed to cater for this, you find that *you* have to be ever vigilant to do so. The onus is on you to determine the subset of the interface available to you that you can use in pure code, fill in the gaps in whatever you think the basic functional toolkit is (maps, folds, option types, etc), wrap pure interfaces around things that refuse to let you use them without mutation, etc, etc. It's not that hard, but it is extra conceptual workload, and it *definitely* reduces some of the benefits of functional programming (error reduction chief among them).

That's what I consider to be the difference between a language that is "really functional" and one that merely "supports functional programming"; whether it makes functional programming easy or hard. And it's really more of a property of the APIs you're interacting with than language features per se.

---

<sup>1</sup> As a digression, I find a basic set of immutable *collections* are far more important to supporting functional programming than immutable *variables*. And even then, it's not actually the immutability that's the issue, it's the API that allows you to use collections without mutating them (which is necessarily present if the collections *are* immutable). Unless you're in a language like Haskell that enforces purity everywhere it's always going to be a matter of programmer discipline to simply refrain from side effects. Choosing not to assign to mutable variables is easy; using a list or map without mutating it when the basic operations one would have on an immutable list or map are not present is much more of a pain.

Comment: Scala was written with OOP as well. I can write OOP in Scala. If I couldn't I wouldn't be able to integrate Java libraries. So the reason you say Groovy isn't as functional are the same reasons that Scala isn't as functional.

Comment: @Orubel If that's what you got from my answer, then I've failed to communicate very well. My entire point was that for a language "bring functional" and "being OO" is not black and white; it's not about whether Scala has the technical features to support OOP, it's that the standard libraries and the culture that informs "idiomatic Scala" very much favour use of pure functional code for large sections of your program - you are encouraged to use recursion, pattern matching, and monads as parts of your daily toolkit. This is not true of Groovy.

Comment: So you are saying that what makes a functional language is how people are encourage to use it? So if I encourage people to use Volkswagon bugs as submarines, are they no longer cars. Monads, pattern matching and recursion is part of the documentation and so, YES... people use it all the time. Still don't see your argument against it as functional.

Comment: @Orubel Yes, that is exactly my point. If the community around a language encourages functional code (starting with the core language maintainers), then functional APIs proliferate (starting with the standard library), and it's easy to write more functional code. To take your ridiculous straw man argument at face value, if a large community of Volkswagon users (including the manufacturers) encourage you to use them as submarines, top the point that car features and infrastructure are developed supporting that use, then yes they are submarines.

Comment: Well there you go then. Groovy starts with the documentation by promoting functional coding. People learn how to code through the documentation. You are basically proving my point. Thanks for agreeing that Groovy IS a functional language as I originally stated :)

Comment: @Orubel I found that not to be the case; the tutorials all used mutability without teaching or showing pure algorithms. The APIs I've interacted with used lots of mutable objects, and outside of basic stdlib lists and maps often didn't provide methods that had all the same functionality with a pure interface. Contrast with Scala; I learned it from the first book listed on Scala's documentation page, which doesn't even mention the *concept* of mutation until 18 chapters in. Immutability is the default, for built in collections and user-defined classes. Most APIs were largely pure.

Comment: And I've found that Scala when interacting with Java uses OOP. In fact this is suggested methodology for working with Java classes in alot of cases. You see, community does not a language make. It;s the paradigm and languages can implement mixed paradigms. And whether people use it or not, the functionality IS THERE. Fortunately, people do use it... in both languages. And to argue that even though the language has implemented the functionality and SOME people use it, that because NOT ENOUGH people do in your opinion, its not functional it poor logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73381/discussion-between-ben-and-orubel).